# Email não envia para endereços hostgator

Tags: php, wordpress, phpmailer

Estou configurando o envio de e-mail no wordpress sem plugin com o wpmail nativo, porém não consigo enviar para um endereço de e-mail hostgator, quando eu envio para o gmail ou outro provedor funciona perfeitamente, porém para endereços não conhecidos ou seja, que sejam diferentes de gmail, outlook, hotmail etc... Não chega nada, falta alguma configuração?

Segue o código do que fiz no wp-config.php, removi a parte da senha por segurança

```
/* Mail Config */
define( 'SMTP_HOST', 'cheapremovals.com' );  // A2 Hosting server name. For example, "a2ss10.a2hosting.com"
define( 'SMTP_AUTH', true );
define( 'SMTP_PORT', '465' );
define( 'SMTP_SECURE', 'ssl' );
define( 'SMTP_USERNAME', 'test@cheapremovals.com' );  // Username for SMTP authentication
define( 'SMTP_FROM',     'test@cheapremovals.com' );  // SMTP From address
define( 'SMTP_FROMNAME', 'Cheap Removals' );         // SMTP From name
```

e no functions.php coloquei isso

```
add_action( 'phpmailer_init', 'send_smtp_email' );
function send_smtp_email( $phpmailer ) {
    $phpmailer->isSMTP();
    $phpmailer->Host       = SMTP_HOST;
    $phpmailer->SMTPAuth   = SMTP_AUTH;
    $phpmailer->Port       = SMTP_PORT;
    $phpmailer->SMTPSecure = SMTP_SECURE;
    $phpmailer->Username   = SMTP_USERNAME;
    $phpmailer->Password   = SMTP_PASSWORD;
    $phpmailer->From       = SMTP_FROM;
    $phpmailer->FromName   = SMTP_FROMNAME;
}
```

Comment: Isto provavelmente é devido a algum filtro de anti-spam do hostgator